# What is the best way to indexing a component of a indexed vector?

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors, tensors

I'm writing some academic stuff. I'd like to make it clear and precise especially in the mathematical expression; but, I got an ambiguity.

When I index something, I often use the subscript. So, I indexed the e-th vector as $\mathbf{v}_e$. Also, I use the subscript indexing the component of a vector:

$\mathbf{u}=\left[u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n\right]^\mathsf{T}$

Then I'd like to specify the component of an (already) indexed vector like:

$\mathbf{v}_e=\left[\cdots,\rm{Here},\cdots\right]^\mathsf{T}$

I've tried:

- $v_e^i$ but it can be confused with exponent...
- $v_{e,i}$ but it can be confused with differential (Einstein notation).
- $v_e^{(i)}$ I think it is a bit verbose and can be confused with $v_i^{(e)}$.

Can anyone recommend anything? In the professional mathematical world, which is the mainstream?

Comment: The indexed vector $v_k$ is the $k^{th}$ column of a matrix, 
$V=\big[v_1\,v_2\,\ldots\,v_n\big].\;$ Therefore the $i^{th}$ component of $v_k$ is _unambiguously_ the matrix element $V_{ik}\;$

Comment: In the notation of the Ricci-Kalkül, the $i$th component of vector $v_e$ is denoted as $v_e^i$ and the first assumption is always that upper indices are contravariant coordinate indices, powers have to be indicated with additional effort, like $(v_e^i)^m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest matrix notation. Let $\mathbf{v} = [\mathbf{v}_1 \ \cdots \ \mathbf{v}_n]^\top$ be the matrix whose rows are your vectors. (Maybe you'd want to use $\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{v}_1^\top \\ \ldots \\ \mathbf{v}_n^\top\end{bmatrix}$.) Then $\mathbf{v}_{ej}$ is the $j$th component of $\mathbf{v}_e$.

Another option would be $\mathbf{v}^{(1)}, \ldots, \mathbf{v}^{(n)}$ for the vectors with $\mathbf{v}^{(e)}_j$ for the $j$th component. I've seen similar things in papers and used them myself.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take this notation in my work :) Off the records, how about the case that every vector does not have the same length?

Comment: @MinsikSeo Matrix notation is perhaps misleading if the vectors differ in length. The $\mathbf{v}^{(e)}_j$ notation handles that better. I've used it in my own papers, though in my context heterogeneous vector lengths can be fixed by padding an infinite string of 0's, so it doesn't bother anyone.